# How to pass dynamic values in a <td> element to a servlet

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets

I have the following code in a JSP getting input from a servlet and passing output to another servlet.

```
  <%ShoppingServlet ss = new ShoppingServlet();
ArrayList<Item> itemList = ss.viewItems(); // results from another servlet

for (Item it: itemList){
    out.print("<tr>");
    out.print("<td>"+it.getId()+"</td>");
    out.print("<td>"+it.getName()+"</td>");
    out.print("<td>"+it.getDesc()+"</td>");
    out.print("<td>"+it.getPrice()+"</td>");
    out.print("<td><input type=\"number\"  min = \"0\" placeholder=\"0\" size=\"2\"></td>");//user input for quantity 
    out.print("</tr>");

}
%>
```

Which generating the following table
[image]

what am trying to do is to allow the user to update the quantities and then pass all the final values to another server.

I thought of printing the values in the "td" elements into "input" elements, but in this case i won't be able to view the values dynamically from the arrayList created by the original servlet.

i wonder if there is a way of getting the generated values and pass them on to the next servlet.

all help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear enough, but as i mentioned in the question, if my values display in an  input element, getting them wouldn't be a problem. but they are displayed dynamically in a table cell element      `out.print("<td>"+it.getId()+"</td>");` and if i'd wrap them in an input tag, i would need to insert the values attributes manually, which doesn't serve the purpose of what am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have your input "name" be of the form item_.  You'll have values like:

Now, when the server submits the form your servlet can iterate over the request parameters. Assuming an HttpServletRequest object named "request":

```
for( String param : request.getParameterNames() ){
   if( param.startsWith("item_") {
      String itemId = param.substr(5);
      String quantity = request.getParameter(param);

      ... update itemId with new quantity ...
   }
}
```

Comment: What is ganna make the form capture the values of Item if if i did not put them in an input tag at the first place? and if so how can i associate the quantity with each item?

Comment: The form will send all the input values.  You associate each one with an ID.  You'll need to check if the value changed and then update your database.  The basic idea is each quantity <input> is associated with the item in the database by an id.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to generate the table inside a form element. Like this:

```
out.print("<form action='/YOUR_SERVLET_MAPPING'>");
for (Item it: itemList){
    out.print("<tr>");
    out.print("<td>"+it.getId()+"</td>");
    out.print("<td>"+it.getName()+"</td>");
    out.print("<td>"+it.getDesc()+"</td>");
    out.print("<td>"+it.getPrice()+"</td>");
    out.print("<td><input name=\"entries\" type=\"number\"  min = \"0\" placeholder=\"0\" size=\"2\"></td>");//user input for quantity 
    out.print("</tr>");
out.print("<input value='Send Data' type='submit'>");
out.print("</form>");
}
```

When "Send Data" is clicked, a request will be made to  /YOUR_SERVLET_MAPPING (your servlet). You can user the getParameterValues (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)
) method to get the values.

```
String values[] = request.getParameterValues("entries");
```

Comment: Actually i have form tags wrapping my scriplet. the problem is, i cannot pass the values of the "Item" object that have been generated from the database